# why we found ULL in the end of patterns used for memory testing?

Tags: c, memory-management, constants, error-checking

What is the utility of adding ULL in the end of patterns written to test the memory ?

For Exemple

```
uint64 pattern_55 =  0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAULL;

static error_t  sram_aa_55_test(uint32 start_address, uint32 tested_area_size)
  {
    error_t status = E_NOERROR;

          /*Patterns used to test every SRAM cell */
    uint64 pattern_aa = 0x5555555555555555ULL;
    uint64 pattern_55 = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAULL;

          /* Current address being tested */
    uint32 address;

          /* data read back in memory */
    uint64 data_read;

          /* AA pattern test */
    memset((uint64*)start_address, pattern_aa, tested_area_size);
    sync();

    for (address = start_address; address < start_address + tested_area_size; address += sizeof(uint64))
    {
            /* read back the memory cell and check that it contains the same pattern we just wrote */
      data_read = rd_io_64(address);

      if (data_read != pattern_aa)
      {
        return CORE_Test_Error;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: That's a suffix to the integer marking it as an `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Please take some time to read through your books, tutorials or class-notes to see if they mention [integer literal type suffixes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant#The_type_of_the_integer_constant).

Comment: If it's available (which it might not be given that non-standard typedefs are used here), `UINT64_C(<number>)` should likely be used instead of directly using type integer suffixes. This ensures that the correct size is used, since type sizes can vary between platforms.

Comment: @ThomasJager ULL is sufficient however. Actually, no suffix is *required* in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of your code snippet it is only for self-commenting the code.

The suffux `llu` is used for explicit specifying that an integer constant has the type `unsigned long long`.

However when a constant is presented in the hexadecimal notation the suffix can be omitted because the compiler itself determines the type of the constant. That is (The C Standard, 6.4.4.1 Integer constants)

> 5 The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding
>   list in which its value can be represented.

And for hexadecimal integer constants

```
int
unsigned int
long int
unsigned long int
long long int
unsigned long long int
```

Comment: @ChristianGibbons It is not important. Either record can be used as for example llu, ull, Ull, llU, LLu, uLL, LLU, ULL.

Answer (score 0):

It's a suffix signifying that integer literal is an unsigned long long.